# Should I use Serverless Computing

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I am creating a MVP(Minimum Viable Product) that has a nodejs server using express for a rest api and a socket.io connection for chat features.

My concern is not so much about cost or scalability, but about setup time/maintenance as this is an MVP. Would serverless or not serverless take less time to setup/maintain on AWS?

Answer (score 1):

Serverless is a great choice is you want to set up a simple REST API application. Using Express would also be a good choice.

API Gateway and Serverless also now supports websockets, so it should be pretty easy to create a websocket application. When it comes to socket.io, however, you will need to do a bit of research before diving in. 
Websocket support on API Gateway is a relatively new concept, and there aren't too many resources online on it. The combination with Lambda can be a little difficult to grasp at first. As for socket.io there are even less.

I personally recommend running a EC2 instance running socket.io for your MVP. I think it'd be easier.

Answer (score 1):

There are several reasons to choose a serverless infrastructure over non-serverless.  In many cases these align very closely with 5 Pillars of the AWS Well-Architected Framework.  Serverless architectures offer great:

- Reliability - no need to guess capacity, can easily scale horizontally with demand
- Efficiency - tremendously reduced costs for intermittent and infrequent workloads
- Maintenance - nonexistent
- Availability - highly available and fault tolerant

While your proposed project does appear to fit well within the FaaS framework (infrequent and unpredictable workload with low resource requirements), the disadvantages of serverless, notably the more complex and difficult to test architecture and vendor lock-in can make it challenging to rapidly prototype and deploy a MVP.

As your product favors an engineering tradeoff toward time to market, a non-serverless approach will most likely enable you to release a MVP quickly with minimal headache

Answer (score 0):

There are some serverless frameworks that work on AWS lambda function. By my realworld experience, there are some notices on each of them:

1. AWS Amplify (https://docs.amplify.aws) a full stack serverless solution for developers. It's quite easy to use at the begining. Cons. Is that over the time your maintainance cost is higher on deployment part. It's very slow to deploy a stack on AWS when you just need to change a piece of code. It will download all the stack files to local then upload again...
2. Serverless framework (https://www.serverless.com) is less complex, rich plugins and nano function oriented. The downside of this framework is every code function will be used the same across lambdas. When the project is bigger, the code size is bigger therefore your lambda's cold start is slower.
3. Simplify framework (https://github.com/simplify-framework/codegen) sounds a lightweight but rich functionalities. It allows you build your CI/CD inside your project. This concept is similar with AWS CDK has just released a couple of days in May. You design your API using OpenAPI specs (swagger specs) that will be reused and standardized your APIs across tools and processes. No vender lock-in has been desiged carefully. Today you are in AWS but tomorrow it will be on your on-premise servers.

You choose what fits to your solution. There is no one fit all.